# Optimised Javascript for HTML5 Video player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have a HTML5 video player on my site with three videos. The code I found only supported one video per webpage but I managed to do a hack to make it work with multiple videos per page. The hack is pretty inefficient and I am sure there is a more elegant way to implement this. Here is how my code looks:

```
 // Video
        var video = document.getElementById("video");
        var video2 = document.getElementById("video2");
        var video3 = document.getElementById("video3");

        // Buttons
        var playButton = document.getElementById("play-pause");
        var playButton2 = document.getElementById("play-pause2");
        var playButton3 = document.getElementById("play-pause3");

        // Event listener for the play/pause button 1
        playButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (video.paused == true) {
                // Play the video
                video.play();
                // Update the button text to 'Pause'
                document.getElementById("play-pause").className = "pause";
            } else {
                // Pause the video
                video.pause();

                // Update the button text to 'Play'
                document.getElementById("play-pause").className = "play";
            }
        });

        // Event listener for the play/pause button 2
        playButton2.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (video2.paused == true) {
                // Play the video
                video2.play();
                // Update the button text to 'Pause'
                document.getElementById("play-pause2").className = "pause";
            } else {
                // Pause the video
                video2.pause();

                // Update the button text to 'Play'
                document.getElementById("play-pause2").className = "play";
            }
        });

        // Event listener for the play/pause button 3
        playButton3.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (video3.paused == true) {
                // Play the video
                video3.play();
                // Update the button text to 'Pause'
                document.getElementById("play-pause3").className = "pause";
            } else {
                // Pause the video
                video3.pause();

                // Update the button text to 'Play'
                document.getElementById("play-pause3").className = "play";
            }
        });

    }
```

As you can see I went down the route of simply duplicating the event listener and creating new variables. There must be a way to select the target based on the specific Div selected, maybe through specifying the path of the class? I.e. .container .video1 .play?

The second problem I am having is reverting the pause button and poster image back to the original state after the video has finished playing.

Here is the site where the code and content is placed:

http://www.glowdigital.net/index.php?page=snap-inspire

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There must be a way to select the target based on the specific Div selected, maybe through specifying the path of the class?

Yes there are better ways of event handling a group of elements.

- Event delegation is when the event listener is registered on an ancestor element that the target elements have in common.
- Arrays can be used by keeping track of an index number.

The following demo will address the latter.

> The second problem I am having is reverting the pause button and poster image back to the original state after the video has finished playing.

Many ways to handle that. The demo demonstrates the use of the CSS `::after` pseudo-element and `add/removeClass()` methods.

I also added exclusive playback capabilities as well. If a player is playing and 
another player starts to play, the player that was playing will stop playing.

**Details are commented in demo**

### Demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>HTML5 Video Player Group - Exclusive Playback</title>
  <style>
    button {
      color: rgba(66, 200, 150, 1);
      background: none;
      border: 0;
      font: 400 24px/1 Verdana;
      outline: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    button:hover,
    button:active,
    button:focus {
      color: #0F3
    }
    
    .play.toPause::after {
      content: '⏸';
      font: inherit;
    }
    
    .play.toPlay::after {
      content: '▶';
      font: inherit;
    }
    
    .stop::after {
      content: '⏹';
      font: inherit;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header> </header>
  <main id="media">
    <figure class="vSection">
      <video id="v0" width="320" height="auto" poster="http://www.glowdigital.net/images/projects/snap-inspire-1.jpg">
         <source src="http://www.glowdigital.net/images/projects/snap-inspire-1.webm" type="video/webm">
         <source src="http://www.glowdigital.net/images/projects/snap-inspire-1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      <figcaption class="controls">
        <button type="button" class="play toPlay"></button>
        <button type="button" class="stop"></button>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="vSection">
      <video id="v1" width="320" height="auto" poster="http://www.glowdigital.net/images/projects/snap-inspire-2.jpg">
         <source src="http://www.glowdigital.net/images/projects/snap-inspire-2.webm" type="video/webm">
         <source src="http://www.glowdigital.net/images/projects/snap-inspire-2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      <figcaption class="controls">
        <button type="button" class="play toPlay"></button>
        <button type="button" class="stop"></button>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="vSection">
      <video id="v2" width="320" height="auto" poster="http://www.glowdigital.net/images/projects/snap-inspire-3.jpg">
         <source src="http://www.glowdigital.net/images/projects/snap-inspire-3.webm" type="video/webm">
         <source src="http://www.glowdigital.net/images/projects/snap-inspire-3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      <figcaption class="controls">
        <button type="button" class="play toPlay"></button>
        <button type="button" class="stop"></button>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </main>
  <footer>&nbsp;</footer>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Gather all <video> into a NodeList then convert it into an array
    var videos = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('video'));

    /* map() through array assigning an id to each <video>
    || vArray is returned; an array of <video id='..'>
    */
    var vArray = videos.map(function(vid, idx) {

      var player = document.getElementById(vid.id);

      return player;

    });


    // When a button.play is clicked...   
    $('.play').on('click', function(e) {
      // Get it's index number
      var idx = $('.play').index(this);
      /* Invoke functiom excPlay passing the vArray and idx
      || It stops any player if it's playing and the prepares
      || the specified player to play. See bottom of source
      || for details
      */
      var player = excPlay(vArray, idx);
      // If paused or ended...   
      if (player.paused || player.ended) {
        // Play video
        player.play();
        // Switch the classes for the all buttons to the paused state
        $('.play').removeClass('toPause').addClass('toPlay');
        // Switch this button to the playing state
        $(e.target).addClass('toPause').removeClass('toPlay');

      }
      //...Otherwise...
      else {
        // Pause the video
        player.pause();
        // Switch all buttons to the paused state
        $('.play').removeClass('toPause').addClass('toPlay');

      }
      // Click thebutton.stop...
      $('.stop').on('click', function(e) {
        // Get index number
        var index = $('.stop').index(this);
        // See line 73
        var player = excPlay(vArray, index);
        // Pause the video
        player.pause();
        // Set video's time back to 0
        player.currentTime = 0;
      });

      // If a video ends...
      $('video').on('ended', function() {
        // Reset the time
        this.currentTime = 0;
        // Get its poster value...
        var image = this.poster;
        // ,,,then set it
        this.poster = image;

        // Set all buttons to pause state
        $('.play').removeClass('toPause').addClass('toPlay');
      });

      /* Pass in an array of video objects and the index number of 
      || thevideo you want to play.
      */
      function excPlay(array, exclude) {
        // map() the array of videos; on each loop...
        array.map(function(video, index) {
          // If the video isn't the video you want to play...
          if (index != exclude) {
            // Get the video's poster
            var image = video.poster;
            // Set the time back to the beginning
            video.currentTime = 0;
            // Pauase video
            video.pause();
            // Reset the poster image
            video.poster = image;

          }

        });
        // Toggle the classes on the play button
        $('.play').removeClass('toPause').addClass('toPlay');
        // Return the selected player or nothing
        return array[exclude] || null;
      }

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Zer00ne, Thank you for taking the time to answer my question and look at my code. This solution appears to work. Thanks again

Comment: Not a problem. It looks like you put a lot of work into your project, I knew you'd appreciate and make good use of the code I posted. Happy coding.